# How To Prevent CICD Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

- I have one branch in gitlab and 2 people committed in the same time
  in the same branch , so i want to prevent gitlab CI/CD pipeline to
  work parallel , the first committed should work first on pipeline and
  after the first pipeline finished .,  the second pipeline  start

  Could you please help me to how to do this ?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#auto-cancel-redundant-pipelines

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a `resource_group:`
See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/ for detail